# Set title attribute if content overflows

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 6.
I have a fixed width element with a string inside. I've set the css so if the string overflows, 3 dots (ellipsis) are showed.
Now, in cases of overflows, I want to set the title attribute so the user can view the full string just hovering it.

I'm searching for the less invasive/best/elegant/correct method to do it.

So far I've tried 2 approaches:

**METHOD 1 (PIPE)**

```
.truncate {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

@Pipe({
    name: "titlePipe"
})
export class TitlePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(title: string, element: HTMLElement) {
        return element.scrollWidth > element.offsetWidth ? title : "";
    }
}

<div #pname class="truncate" [title]="photoItem.Name | titlePipe:pname">{{photoItem.Name}}</div>
```

Unfortunately this method is not working because the pipe runs when the element is not fully loaded yet.

**METHOD 2**

```
.truncate {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

<div #pname class="truncate" [title]="pname.scrollWidth > pname.offsetWidth ? photoItem.Name : ''">{{photoItem.Name}}</div>
```

This method is working, but is throwing an error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'title: '. Current value: 'title: dummy-2000x2000-FairyLights.jpg'.
```

What is the best and less invasive method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid the expression has Changed error using ChangeDetectorRef service
and use detectChanges method to Force change detection

This will Work

```
import{ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
```